# How to Submit Https authentication with Selenium in python

Tags: python, firefox, authentication, selenium, form-submit

I want to access with **Selenium** (through) Python, a URL that demands authentication.

When visit the URL, manually a new authentication window pops up, on which I need to fill in a *username* and *password*. Only after clicking on “OK” this window disappears and I return to the original site.

As I want to visit this URL on an interval base to download information and want to automatize this process in python.

In my current effort I use **Selenium**, but none of the examples that I found seem to do what I need. Thinks I tried but do not work are:

- `driver.get("https://username:password@somewebsite.com/")`
- `selenium.FireEvent("OK", "click")`
- `driver.find_element_by_id("UserName")`

I do not know the actual element id’s

What I did manage is to load my Firefox profile that stores the authentication information, but I still need to confirm the authentication by clicking “ok”.

Is there any way to prevent this screen to pop up?

If not how to access this button on the authentication form, from which I cannot obtain id-information?

Answer (score 1):

Using `driver.get("https://username:password@somewebsite.com/")` should directly log you in, without the popup being displayed,

What about this did not work for you?

**EDIT**

---

I am not sure this will work but after
`driver.get("https://username:password@somewebsite.com/")`

Try accepting alert.

*For the alert* - `@driver.switch_to.alert.accept` in Ruby or `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();` in Java

Comment: Thats indeed what I figured out from all the examples I found, but this does not work for me. I still get the authentication popup, with the pasword and username already filled in; however, I still need to click the button 'OK' to actually continue.

Comment: Ps. I made a error in my origanal text. It should not be driver.get("https://username:password@somewebsite.com/") but instead: driver.get("http://username:password@somewebsite.shtml/"). I do not know how much this matters.

Comment: Warning - the address MUST be written as whole. So if the authentification lies on http://example.com/somewebsite.shtml, the way how to get there using Selenium is `driver.get("https://username:password@example.com/somewebsite.shtml/")`

Comment: I have the exact same issue and it beats me. I can't get passed the auth although it's passed in the URL.

Comment: Doesn't look like the auth dialog is seen as an alert by the ChromeDriver. So you can't accept it